# How to handle empty xml node in freemarker

Tags: xpath, freemarker

I am trying to parse an xml to json using freemarker . Its working if the mentioned tag is there in the input XML but getting an error if the tag itself is not there . In this case getting error if the UR_DETAIL tag is not there in the XML. How  i can handle it ? Can i handle it in assign line itself ?

```
<#assign UR = SUBJECTLOAN[".//UR_DETAIL"]>
{
 price : ${UR[".//PurchaseAmount"]} 
}

TemplateModelException: Xalan can't perform an XPath query against an empty Node Set

Expected Out put is 
price: null
```

Comment: Try `<#assign UR = SUBJECTLOAN[".//UR_DETAIL[.//PurchaseAmount]"]>` will select only UR_DETAIL that have a PurchaseAmount child

Comment: That Actually works , But in a more generic way is there anyway i create a function which receive the node and return empty node if its null .

Comment: <#function check node >
    if(node is null )
 return empty node or null value 
 else 
 return node 
</#function>

Comment: And call it like 
 price : ${check(UR)[".//PurchaseAmount"]}

Comment: Posting answers to own questions is ok, even encouraged here on SO. So if you found an answer it would be good if oyu post it :-)

Comment: If you avoid using `.//`, and just use the dot operator, like `SUBJECTLOAN.FOO.BAR.UR_DETAIL`, that will work even if the `SUBJECTLOAN` was an empty node set.

Comment: Also you aren't dealing with a `null` here, but an empty node set (as the error message says). So you can use `?has_content`, if you have to know if it's empty. Also, using Jaxen instead of Xalan would remove the limitation.